# JLibs internationalization doesn't create _bundle.class and properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, java-6

I am currently switching from C# to Java and I am trying to find a good alternative for the C# resource files to store strings.

The [internationalization of jlibs](https://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/Internationalization) sounds like exactly what I am looking for. But it's just not working for me. If I understand it correctly then it actually should create two files when I compile the project:

- Bundle.properties
- _Bundle.class

But nothing gets created.

Here's some code, which is basically the example on the webpage.

Calling a string from the bundle:

```
package i18n;

import static i18n.UIBundle.UI_BUNDLE;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(UI_BUNDLE.executeButton());
        }
    }
```

The bundle:

```
package i18n;

import jlibs.core.util.i18n.I18N;
import jlibs.core.util.i18n.Message;
import jlibs.core.util.i18n.ResourceBundle;

@ResourceBundle
public interface UIBundle{
    public static final UIBundle UI_BUNDLE = I18N.getImplementation(UIBundle.class);

    @Message("Execute")
    public String executeButton();
}
```

And the error actually telling me, that there's no _Bundle class:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   i18n.Main.main(Main.java:10) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: i18n._Bundle    at
>   jlibs.core.util.i18n.I18N.getImplementation(I18N.java:34)

What I did:

- Created a new Java project in Eclipse
- Added jlibs-core.jar to the Referenced Libraries
- Added the whole jlibs-folder to Java - Build Path - Classpath Variables
- Downloaded xercesImpl.jar and added it to the Referenced Libraries

Did I just miss some basic configuration I am not aware of or do I need some other preconditions? Anyone seeing my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with jlibs so went for [C10N](https://github.com/rodionmoiseev/c10n/wiki/Overview#c10n-usage-overview) instead which works in a very similar way. A simple example, firstly in some startup code tell C10N you want default locales to be used (you can also add your own):

```
C10N.configure(new C10NConfigBase()
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        install(new DefaultC10NAnnotations());
    }
});
```

Then create interfaces with annotated messages:

```
//docs suggest this isn't needed by default but it didn't work without this annotation
@C10NMessages
public interface ExceptionText
{
    @En("That didn't work")
    @De("Das hat nicht geklappt")
    public String simpleMessage();

    //action may need translating too!
    @En("Could not perform action {0}, failure code {1}")
    @De("Aktion {0} ist nicht möglich, Fehlercode {1}")
    public String complexMessage(String action, int code);
}
```

Then using the above elsewhere:

```
String simple = C10N.get(ExceptionText.class).simpleMessage();
String complex = C10N.get(ExceptionText.class).complexMessage("xyz", 123);
```

You can also get it to use resource bundles for translation text if preferred.